# TensorFlow Object Detection API trains only one class instead of multiple classes

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, training-data

I have been trying to fine-tune the SSD Inception v2 model with my own dataset of different kinds of drinks. Unfortunately, when I am training, I found that only one category of class is getting trained but not the rest. I am unsure what I was doing wrong. I have recreated my dataset thrice and tried to train with it, but still I end up with the same results.

[image: Image that shows the performance by category while training]

Is there any particular procedure to be followed, when training Object Detection API with several classes?

Will the tensorflow train one class after another?

Comment: The problem might be in your config file (in num_classes or first_stage_only), or in your label map (is there any category missing there?)

Comment: Yes!! the problem is present in the config file. I found it just few min ago XD. Thanks for the help @gdelab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, the problem is caused due to the config file. I have assigned the num_classes with one instead of three. After i initialized it with three, everything works well now. Sometimes, this kind of issue might also arise due t the issue with the dataset.